# Adding project back under git control?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

So, I have a project that was originally under git version control,
The project has since had all git related files removed (afaik).

So when I try to add it back under version control (using PHP Storm) I get told that

> Some configured Git VCS roots are not under Git or have Git repositories in subdirectories without configured VCS root

Which I am assuming means there is still a trace of git left in there somewhere.

I am using ubuntu so I `cd`'d to the root directory, then did `ls -Ra | grep .git` but nothing showed up. so what am I doing wrong? where could the git stuff be hiding?

and, once I remove it, how do I add this project back into git control? is there other than choosing the right repo that I will need to do?

---

After a bit of research I came across [this article](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-60631?query=git) which seems to say that phpstorm looks to your resource root instead of project root for the version control info.

Now my structure is

/unity/nz <- under it's own version control
/unity/au <- trying to add to version control

So this could be the problem..

So maybe i'll do this without php storm, so my second question still stands,
How do I add this back under version control in the same repo (terminal commands would be useful!)

Comment: What happens when you type `git init` in the project root via terminal?

Comment: `Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/unity/au/.git/`

Comment: I have a feeling it is the sub directories that have something in them...

Comment: I'm not so sure. I think there may be an issue with PHP Storm's implementation of Git. you can safely `rm -rf .git/` from that same directory, and that would destroy the Git repo - it shouldn't be (and isn't based on your `ls -Ra`) in any of the subdirectories.

Comment: Hmm, about to do an update to my question that seems to support your theory

Comment: Maybe you're supposed to create the repo first before using PHP Storm? Edit - just saw your update. Sorry, shot in the dark there, I'm not at all familiar with PHP Storm :) Is `nz` using Git and you'd like to have them under the same repo, or `au` gets its own repo?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3050/discussion-between-hailwood-and-melee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `au` directory, you're just going to repeat the repo "init" process we went through in the comments.

`git init`

Now you've got your repository. You've got two options here; either `add` files for tracking, or setup your `.gitignore` file to start ignoring things that you don't want in your repository. I usually setup `.gitignore` first. You can open it in a text editor and fire away.

After that, you add the `.gitignore` with the following:

`git add .gitignore`

and commit with:

`git commit -m ".gitignore in place"`

With that in place, you can type:

`git add .`

Which adds all of the files in the `au` directory (and subdirectories) for tracking. It'll check the `.gitignore` file first and not include those files for tracking.

You can type `git status` at any time to get some useful information about what you're currently doing. You'll need to `commit` the files you added:

`git commit -m "initial commit"`

And now you're tracking them, so when you save from PHP Storm, you can go back to the terminal and type:

`git status`

This will show you the file that you changed. You can add it (or, if you've made changes to x amount of files, you can add those too) with the `git add .` command. Commit with a helpful message and you're good to go.

At this point, you can setup your github repo as a remote. More info on that [here.](http://help.github.com/remotes/) Once you've done that, you can `push` the current history to github:

(assuming empty remote)

`git push remote master`

I see you're working  on something web related, so I suggest you take a look at [this post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for using a branching model. This helps a lot. If you practice this, I think you'll prefer it to working with a client or any other method :)